# Using pngquant with AppleScript

Tags: macos, png, applescript, image-optimization

Can anybody share an applescript which uses the pngquarnt to optimize images in a folder.
May be even an Apple service be useful.

Note: There is an terminal command to do the same thing, but i am talking about a newbie, who can just right click on an folder containing images and optimize them.

Comment: You could embedd the terminal command in an applescript.

Comment: Couldn't they use [ImageAlpha](http://pngmini.com/)?

Comment: @Lauri, problem with ImageAlpha is that you have to optimize one image at a time. NO batch conversion mode is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the zip from the bellow path and follow the steps from readme
https://github.com/hamdullahshah/Automator-App-for-PngQuant

You can change the arguments by changing the command in "PngCompression WorkFlow" and then save it as application.

Comment: great. Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 1):

This will process all png files in the folder that you select:

```
set myFolder to POSIX path of (choose folder)
set myFiles to do shell script "find " & quoted form of myFolder & " -name *.png -print0 | xargs -0 usr/local/bin/pngquant"
```

EDIT
Hamdullah's answer uses the following line which is very similar to my response:

```
find $@ -name '*.png' -exec pngquant -ext .png -speed 1 -force 256 {} \;
```

However, xargs is preferable to exec when processing large batches of files. It is faster because When you use "-exec", it starts a new process for each file that is found

Comment: this looks good but i am accepting the other answer. As it is more easy for a newbie (especially non tech people). Anyway thanks for the effort.

Comment: You're welcome. I edited my response to give you a bit more bachground.